# DevCPP Make file error

Tags: c++, gcc, tdm-mingw

I am trying to compile the code, but i am getting this error, I don't understand this, and what is wrong with my code

```
# Project: Project1
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.6.0

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = main.o
LINKOBJ  = main.o
LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++"
BIN      = Project1.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
RM       = rm -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure because of the possible reformatting of the text when publising on Stackoverflow, but I have the impression that in the last lines of the code:

```
clean: clean-custom
        ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
        $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

you should have a tab character (and **only** one!) before the lines starting with $.
No spaces or anything else.